# PFQuery pinAllInBackground:block: never completes

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I have a Parse app and I want to enable local data store for caching/offline use. In my app delegate, I've set `[Parse enableLocalDatastore];`.

In my query (to the server), I'm making a normal query, but I'm pinning the results upon fetch:

```
[followingsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    [PFObject pinAllInBackground:objects block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"er: %@", error);
    }];
    ... //rest of my handler
}];
```

However, the completion block (`NSLog(@"er: %@", error);`) is never called. Not even with an error. I've got breakpoints everywhere. `pinAllInBackground:block:` is called, but it's completion handler is never called (my app's been running for 2 minutes straight, it's pinning only 100 objects, so it should be instantaneous). I've also tried `pinAllInBackground:withName:block:` but no difference. I've tried `pinAll:` and it just never returns, blocking the calling thread (it doesn't consume any CPU though). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug that I have experienced when running a nested `inBackground`-type method inside another `inBackground`-type method in Parse. The current workaround is to use a different dispatch method, such as Grand Central Dispatch.

Try this:

```
[followingsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        id result = [PFObject pinAll:objects error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog("error: %@", error);
        } 
    });
}];
```

Comment: it worked, but now I'm getting the following error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to find non-existent uuid 1DF77D29-3FCD-4657-BC24-9AB0BF89C987'

any suggestions on that one? (it crashes the app!)

Comment: Are you querying for UUIDs as part of the query?

Comment: Nope, I didnt even know Parse objects had uuids until I saw this error today :)

Comment: By the way, after starting to use local cache, app sometimes started to log me out (i was logged in with Facebook) randomly when I opened the app. After these random logouts, I get this error when I tap login with Facebook again.

Comment: Regarding your logout problem, add a new question here on SO and I'd be happy to take a look. (I don't want to answer a separate problem in the comments since it makes it harder for others to find the solution!)

Comment: You are right, it deserves its own question. I just need to nail it down. (I've currently disabled pinning as it's extremely buggy in every other aspect and the logout problem seems to have gone away though)

Comment: Good plan. I'm holding off on using the iOS local datastore until I see less bug questions here on SO :)

Comment: Exactly, local datastore is a great idea but the implementation is just too buggy for prime time yet. I have a feed-based app and I was going to use it for caching for app start (for loading previous feed immediately while refresing in background) and I ended up adding a category to `PFObject` with `NSCoding` support to save/reload between sessions. It's hacky/a little buggy, but works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at their Docs on how to query local datastore :

For your reference :

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#localdatastore-find/iOS

Comment: obviously. if you read my question and the link that you've pasted, you'd see that the patterns are the same.

Comment: it may be related to this though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435725/enabling-local-data-store-on-parse-by-calling-enablelocaldatastore-before-initia

Comment: if your not getting that same error then you have a different issue: have you tried implementing the code they suggested? [[query findInBackground] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
}

Comment: have you logged your objects array for pinning here : [PFObject pinAllInBackground] and made sure its not nil?

Comment: yeah, there are 50 objects in the array.

Comment: so try setting a match whereKey: equalTo: just to see if will return objects then, if not you might have a bug i'm not sure from this point of view.

Comment: I've updated the question. It appears to be a problem with pinning in the first place.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I am a Parse user and love helping people fix their Parse issues, unfortunately i have not had enough time to review their new SDK beyond the blog they posted. I would suggest offering a bounty to attract more opportunities for successful answer. It's a shame they don't have an active moderator to answer these questions like that have in the past

Comment: Yeah, all big companies should have at least one person regularly watching SO tags about them every several hours. I'll offer a bounty once the question is eligible if I still haven't found the solution.